# How do I describe C-z?

Tags: key-bindings, help, prefix-keys

I tried to bind a key using a prefix-key of `C-z`, but Emacs told me: `Key sequence C-z c starts with non-prefix key C-z`. I guess this means that `C-z` is already bound to something.

So I tried to do `M-x describe-key RET C-z`, but when I do that it doesn't describe that key, it just waits for the next key press (by adding a hyphen after `C-z`).

How can I tell describe-key that I just want to know what `C-z` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `C-z C-h`.

That shows you a list of all the keys, and their commands, that have `C-z` as a prefix key.

Comment: When I press `C-z C-h` I'm told that the following are bound: C-z C-b, C-z b, C-z o, C-z p, C-z q, C-z r, C-z s, C-z t. But emacs was complaining when I tried to set: `;  (("C-z c" . avy-goto-char-timer)
;   ("C-z l" . avy-goto-line)
;   ("C-C j" . avy-resume))` I'm sorry, but I cannot figure out how to put newlines here, every time I hit enter, it saves the comment.

Comment: Sounds like a different question. Your question here is about telling *"describe-key that I just want to know what C-z is?"*. In any case, please put all info about a question in the question itself - comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: For your second question (but please pose it as a separate question): Specify what keymap(s) you're talking about. An answer as to how to bind a key is specific to the map you want to define it for.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed did open a new question about this!

Comment: What *keymap* are you trying to bind to?  What you've shown us in your comment is just data, and insufficient to indicate how the data is being used.  I would *guess* that you're trying to bind to the global map, and therefore need to `(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") nil)` to remove the standard global binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function `describe-key` directly, either by evaluating it in a scratch buffer, or by using the `eval-expression` command (bound to `M-:`).

For example: `M-: (describe-key "\C-z") RET`