# How to use prefix C-SPC instead of prefix C-h, for `which-key-mode-map`?

Tags: prefix-keys, which-key

I'd like to change the `C-h` prefix to `C-SPC` and so I added the following to my init.el, but it has no effect.

`(define-key which-key-mode-map (kbd "<C-SPC>") 'which-key-C-h-dispatch)`

Help understanding how to make this change would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I describe C-z?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54779/how-do-i-describe-c-z)

Comment: @Drew: it might be related but it seems like a fairly different circumstance (doesn't mention the same error, and it's specific to the `which-key` package).

Comment: @Stefan: OK; I wasn't sure. Seemed to be about replacing one prefix key with another.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl is 2^26, SPC is 0x20, so C-SPC is 0x4000020.

Set variable help-char to C-SPC:
(setq help-char #x4000020)

See elisp manual for more detail: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keyboard-Events.html#Keyboard-Events